# Function to drop an R data.table column while returning the dropped column?

Tags: r, data.table

I'd like a function that will permanently drop a named column from an R data.table, and then return the dropped column as a vector.   If the named column doesn't exist in the table, it should gracefully return NA without changing the table.  The table is expected to be large, and the function will be called in a loop, so ideally it would return the column without a copy.  It definitely should not copy the entire table.

Currently I have this:

```
dropColumn = function(table, column) {
    index = match(column, names(table))
    if (is.na(index)) return(NA);    
    dropped = table[[index]]
    set(table, j=index, value=NULL)
    dropped
}
```

I think this does what I want:

```
  library(data.table)
  dt = data.table(a=1:10, b=11:20)
  address(dt)
  # [1] "0x101564d30"
  address(dt$a)
  # [1] "0x10254e7a8"
  c = dropColumn(dt, "a")
  address(c)
  # [1] "0x10254e7a8"  # same as dt$a was above
  names(dt)
  # [1] "b"
  address(dt)
  # [1] "0x101564d30"  # unchanged from above
```

But I suspect there might be a more direct way.   Is there?

Comment: Your way looks fine to me.

Comment: I would do `print(table[, column, with = F]); table[ , (column) := NULL]` but I guess that's stylistic, really.